# Replacing UITabbar items with buttons - Apple Accepts/Rejects

Tags: ios, uibutton, app-store, uitabbarcontroller

In my app, i am making UITabBarController as root view controller. But i am hiding all the UITabbar items using following code to display custom buttons on the tab bar.

```
for(UIView *view in APPDEL.tabBarController.view.subviews)
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITabBar class]])
        {
            view.hidden = YES;
            break;
        }
    }
```

After hiding the tab bar items, i am adding buttons to the UITabBarController so it looks similar to UITabBarController. Please don't ask me why i am doing this. If we use UITabBarController, then we have to make first index of tab bar to be selected by default. But my client does not want this. So we are adding buttons on tab bar hiding its items.
Im adding buttons on tab bar using following code.

```
[APPDEL.tabBarController.view  addSubview: button1];
```

Does apple rejects my app because of this? Am i breaking apple tab bar controller rules?

Thanks in advance
Jithen

Comment: check this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528248/uibutton-for-tabbar and this:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226297/replace-tab-bar-button-in-uitabbar-with-a-uibutton

Comment: Why use `UITabBarController`? Create your own container view controller class that uses buttons to switch views.

Comment: I am using UITabBarController only because it occupies little space (say 50 pixels) for tab bar... So even if my main view is bigger  it will not draw below my tab bar... iPhone automaticcally adjusts its view dimensions... so using this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes  you can do this way, apple will not reject your application, because it will look like custom tabBar, and everyone can make custom tabBar. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this exactly. I will post if the app is approved.

Comment: It was approved. So I guess Apple doesn't have problems about this.